# How to bind dependency property to datacontext of datatemplate in silverlight without throwing error?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, datagrid, datacontext

I've been having some trouble in my silverlight app, and am hoping one of you may help me. :) I am attempting to set up a datatemplate for a datagrid but am having some trouble with a binding. It seems that when I set my binding mode to "TwoWay", I get the following error:

*Note that I am trying to bind to the DataContext that is automatically "assigned" to the datatemplate*

```
Provide value on 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception.
```

Can anyone provide me with a solution to this problem? My objective is to have the datatemplate in a separate view to allow greater customization to my datagrid. The following is a dumbed down version of what I am attemping:

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding items}" SelectedItem="{Binding selItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
       <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
           <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <View:leadDataTemplate item="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Where `<View:leadDataTemplate item="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"/>` would be the view I am attempting to initialize.

Hopefully you get the idea, thanks in advance for any suggestions or answers!

**Edit:**
*Note that `item` is the dependency property, and it doesn't matter if the source is updated when changes are made to the item, I simply need the datagrid to display information within the `item`, so I require the dependency property to be set, thanks!*

**Second edit:**
*I believe the problem may be that my Binding isn't passing any data at all to the view, do you know why this would be? I know that the `items` section is being filled, so why would the binding be empty? Also, please note that the dependency property is supposed to update another viewmodel as follows:*

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty itemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("item", typeof(object), typeof(leadDataTemplate), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(itemChanged)));
        public leadStreamData item
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(itemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(itemProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void itemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ctrl = (leadDataTemplate)d;
            if (ctrl != null)
                ctrl._vm.item = ctrl.item;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need the binding in `View:leadDataTemplate` to be `TwoWay`?

Comment: Otherwise it doesn't seem to affect my dependency property.. I'm not really sure why this is

Answer (score 0):

TwoWay binding is only required when you wish to update the source data.

The following should suffice:

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding items}" SelectedItem="{Binding selItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
       <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
           <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <View:leadDataTemplate item="{Binding .}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

To use TwoWay binding, you must provide a Path property e.g.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Really? That's what I thought at first, so maybe I'm just missing something now. It seems that when I do this, the dependency property doesn't receive any change..